# Run scripts through ssh

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssh, yarnpkg, openssh

I currently have an EC2 instance with ubuntu installed on it and I'm trying to run a command on it through ssh. Here's what I have so far, once I log into the server manually through ssh and run a command like `yarn --version` it works fine and returns the version of yarn installed on the machine but running the same command through ssh like so

```
ssh user@server "yarn --version"
```

return the following error

```
Yarn requires Node.js 4.0 or higher to be installed.
```

I also ran a whoami which returned the correct user when run through ssh as well as when manually logged in. What am I missing here?

Comment: try ``ssh -t -t user@server "yarn --version"``

Comment: Tried that, got the same response that `Yarn requires Node.js 4.0 or higher to be installed`

Comment: Probably one of the startup files like ``.profile`` isn't being read.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell  for a discussion